# Change width/height depending on class with data-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, custom-data-attribute

I have the following JS code that changes the `width` depending on value of the `data-percentage` HTML attribute:

```
var addRule = (function (sheet) {
  if(!sheet) return;
  return function (selector, styles) {
    if (sheet.insertRule) return sheet.insertRule(selector + " {" + styles + "}", sheet.cssRules.length);
    if (sheet.addRule) return sheet.addRule(selector, styles);
  }
}(document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length - 1]));

var i = 101;
while (i--) {
  addRule("[data-percentage='" + i + "%']", "width:" + i + "%");
}
```

See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YYF35/

Instead of `width`, for some elements I want to change their `height`.

How can I change the code so that depending on class of the `div` I change the height or width of element (depending on the `data-percentage` attribute number of course)?

I don’t want to create a different HTML attribute for it, like so:

```
while (i--) {
  addRule("[data-percentage-width='" + i + "%']", "width:" + i + "%");
  addRule("[data-percentage-height='" + i + "%']", "height:" + i + "%");
}
```

jQuery can be used as well. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you really need to modify the stylesheet, or could you just change the elements? For that matter, why not just hardcode 100 rules into the stylesheet? (Well, 200 rules if you want separate width and height.) `div[data-percentage-height=1].change-height { height: 1% }` and such?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is adding rules. If you really want to be doing that, just add more rules:

```
var i = 101;
while (i--) {
  addRule("[data-percentage='" + i + "%'].change-width", "width:" + i + "%");
  addRule("[data-percentage='" + i + "%'].change-height", "height:" + i + "%");
}
```

Now, elements with the `change-width` class will have their `width` modified, and elements with the `change-height` class will have their `height` modified (and you can use both if you like).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("div[data-percentage]").each(function(){

    $(this).css({
        width: $(this).attr('data-percentage')
        //height: $(this).attr('data-percentage')
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YYF35/1/

Comment: Look at the code again. It's building a *stylesheet*, not changing the elements themselves.